# How can you loop through your own class and print them?

Tags: c++, class, for-loop, oop, vector

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>


class Enemy
{
public:
    std::string type;
};

void add_enemy(std::vector<Enemy>&enemies, Enemy enemy);

int main()
{
    
    Enemy nrone, nrtwo, nrthree, nrfour, nrfive;
    // I want to add these and keep them in a vector
    std::vector<Enemy> enemies;
    
    
    nrone.type = "Orc";
    nrtwo.type = "Goblin";
    nrthree.type = "Troll";
    nrfour.type = "Ogre";
    nrfive.type = "Orc";
    
    add_enemy(enemies, nrone);
    add_enemy(enemies, nrtwo);
    add_enemy(enemies, nrthree);
    add_enemy(enemies, nrfour);
    add_enemy(enemies, nrfive);
    
    std::cout << enemies.size() << std::endl;
    
    for(auto enemy: enemies)
        std::cout << enemy << " " << std::endl;
        
    
    return 0;
}

void add_enemy(std::vector<Enemy>&enemies, Enemy enemy)
{
        enemies.push_back(enemy);
}
```

I am practicing with vectors and classes because I tend to forget things rather quickly if I don't write code. Here I created a class which I named `Enemy`, and I only gave it one public attribute, which is `std::string type;`. Then I proceeded to make a bunch of `Enemy` objects called `nrone`, `nrtwo`, etc. and specify the type for each: orc, goblin, etc.

Then I created a function to add them inside a vector instead of using push back directly (I did this for myself, to practice with functions & passing by reference). I know it doesn't make sense because it's easier to use push back.

Anyway, now I try to loop through the vector and output, ideally, `Orc, Goblin, Troll, Ogre, Orc` to the screen, but it doesn't work. My compiler says --- *error, no match for operator and Enemy*

What's happening? I tried using the ranged foor loop using a standard `std::vector<std::string>names{"Joe", "Jim", "Jessy"};` and it worked, but it doesn't work for my `Enemy` class.

Comment: the issue is not looping but printing on the screen. Start by printing a single `Enemy`. Error and solution will be the same

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 omg thanks a lot! I changed the printing to the screen to 'enemy.type' and it worked

Comment: `class` with only public members is a `struct`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a ostream function that takes your class.

Try adding friend function for this to your `Enemy` class.

```cpp
class Enemy
{
public:
   std::string type;
   friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Enemy& enemy)
   {
      os << "type: " << enemy.type;
      return os;
   }
};
```